# Using awk to iterate through list of files?

Tags: unix, awk

I'm pretty unfamiliar with `awk`, but I am looking for a way to iterate through all files in a directory and execute a simple `awk` command. My command is a simple substitution that replaces all tabs with two spaces.

```
awk '{gsub("\t","  ");print}'
```

How can this be extended to loop through a directory and execute the command on all files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the files to *awk* on the command line of course:

```
$ awk 'program' *
```

But probably it is easier to use

```
$ perl -pe 's/\t/  /g' *
```

Or, if you would rather have an in place edit, simply:

```
$ perl -i.orig -pe 's/\t/  /g' *
```

Comment: do you know if perl be used to join together another substitution ex. `awk '{gsub("\t"," ");print}' | sed "s/foo/bar/g"`? If so, than perl might be the best solution as you stated.

Comment: @dr.bunsen: Yes, of course, just separate commands with a semicolon: `perl -pe 's/\t/  /g; s/foo/bar/g'`

Comment: thank you! i think ill start trying to learn perl, these commands are really convenient as one liners!

Answer (score 1):

an improved version of Heisenbug's idea

```
find . -type f -exec awk '{gsub("\t"," ");print}' {} \;
```

it avoids calling another program like xargs. It seems to be a bit faster with some tests I did.

Answer (score 0):

use find and redirect the output to awk:

```
find . -type f | xargs awk '{gsub("\t"," ");print}'
```

Comment: That looks at filenames, not at file contents.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with one `awk` command

```
awk -F"\t" '{$1=$1;print $0 >FILENAME}' OFS=" " file
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful snippet, that shows awk processing a list of files as if it is one stream (notice how the line number is used)

```
find $HOME/.ssh -name "*.pub" -type f \
  -exec awk '{printf "%c) %12s %s...%s %s\n", 64 + NR, $1, substr($2,1,7), substr($2,length($2)-7), $3}' \
  {} +
```

example output

```
A)      ssh-dss AAAAB3N...WhdJHA== bob@your.uncle
B)  ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3N...9a5kCpbT bob@your.uncle
C)      ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...fzh3oUGZ bob@your.uncle
```