# sed/awk substitute second occurrence of wildcard selection

Tags: xml, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file.. it has many lines but the ones relevant may look like:

```
<name></name>
<name>LED_1</name>
<name>Action Button_8</name>
<name>Action Button_1</name>
<name>LED_1</name>
<name>Label_59</name>
<name>Label_83</name>
```

These names need to be edited for use of an index set at runtime and another I'd like to set here, would be nice to keep their widget type (Label, LED, etc.) intact. There's only ever 3-7 lines with /name> in any file, so I don't mind changing a one liner to fix each occurrence separately within a folder containing my files.

I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/_.*<\/name>/_${DINDEX}_1<\/name>/2'
```

but I think it's looking to replace the second occurrence in each line, not 2nd in a file.
Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
desired result

```
<name></name>
<name>LED_${DINDEX}_1</name>
<name>Action Button_${DINDEX}_2</name>
<name>Action Button_${DINDEX}_3</name>
<name>LED_${DINDEX}_4</name>
<name>Label_${DINDEX}_5</name>
<name>Label_${DINDEX}_6</name>
```

Comment: Are those lines all from one file? What do you want to translate those line to?

Comment: Yes they are all from one file. I'd like to keep their names before _ intact. And replace whatever number they have to say ${DINDEX}_0 for the first occurrence, ${DINDEX}_1 for the second occurrence etc. I've edited my initial question as example. @EtanReisner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk '/<name>[^_]*_/ {sub(/_[^<]*/, "_${DINDEX}_" ++i)} 1' file
<name></name>
<name>LED_${DINDEX}_1</name>
<name>Action Button_${DINDEX}_2</name>
<name>Action Button_${DINDEX}_3</name>
<name>LED_${DINDEX}_4</name>
<name>Label_${DINDEX}_5</name>
<name>Label_${DINDEX}_6</name>
```

Comment: This worked great! If I was greedy I'd go one step further and iterate on all files within the current directory. Thank you! @anubhava

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15953868/3976689, I'd like to iterate on files in current directory. But also to overwrite the files used as input with the output. Is this easily do-able? Hope its okay to ask successive questions like this. Thank you again. @anubhava

Comment: You can do: `for f in *; do awk '/<name>[^_]*_/ {sub(/_[^<]*/, "_${DINDEX}_" ++i)} 1' "$f" > "$f".tmp && mv "$f".tmp $f"; done`. Hope it helps.

Comment: That does help, immensely. This is a tool I'll use to retrofit XML coded templates with unique widget name tags, making them immensely more manageable in screen development.

Comment: It could be noted that there is one " missing before the last $f

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Crisp: You get the same desired output using perl one liner on command prompt as :

```
perl -lpe "$n;s/_[^<]*/_\${DINDEX}_$n/;$n=$n+1" inputfile
```

Comment: This would be for a single file, where $n is the index of occurrence? Could I simply implant that instead of the awk script above and use the same for f in *; do "___________" "$f" > "$f".tmp && mv "$f".tmp "$f"; done?